# Tenho um site multi-línguas, em questão de SEO qual o melhor: Usar Subdomínios ou Diretórios?

Tags: seo

Estou criando um site com vários idiomas (Português, Espanhol, Inglês).

Na questão do **SEO** qual é a maneira mais correta de se usar?

Subdomínios ( `pt.meusite.com` ) ou Diretórios ( `meusite.com/pt` ) ?

Visto que aos olhos do `Google` usar um subdomínio, seria como se fosse um novo site, um site separado sem nenhuma ligação ao site principal.

Penso que utilizar um diretório seja a melhor solução, até mesmo pelo PageRank. Mas tenho receio de pensar que estou fazendo bem e estou fazendo muito mal.

Vi em um artigo que **só é recomendado** usar subdomínios em sites de muito conteúdo, e que retratam **diferentes conteúdos**, como é o caso do Stack Exchange, UOL, G1, Terra, Estadão, IG, R7, etc.

Meu site vai tratar do mesmo conteúdo, só o que irá mudar são os idiomas, e algumas coisas, pois irei vender alguns produtos por países (Brasil, México, Portugal e Espanha), então precisa mudar os preços, moedas, informações, etc...

Um exemplo no UOL:

Para notícias somente de Economia: http://economia.uol.com.br

para somente Carros: http://carros.uol.com.br

Comment: Veja os sites da Stack Exchange que é uma rede enorme. Você vê stackoverflow.com/pt ou pt.stackoverflow.com? Eis a sua resposta :)

Comment: Sim @BrunoAugusto você quer comparar uma rede com dezenas de sites diferentes, com conteúdos diferentes e com milhões de acessos, com apenas um site com cópias em outras línguas? Acho que você não me entendeu.

Comment: Não vou excluir a minha opinião. Metodologia é um conceito e conceitos devem ser aplicados antes mesmo de considerar o grau de popularidade de um site ou quantos outros sites o programador/empresa tem.

Comment: *Taum tá*... *Cês* querem me deixar doido :p

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre SEO. Ver [votação relevante no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1460).

Comment: @Kyllopardiun Tomei a liberdade de alterar um pouco seu último comentário e incluir um link.

Comment: @bfavaretto ok, acho interessante ter esse link e havia esquecido de por o mesmo nesse comentário.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Veja o exemplo do Twitter e do Facebook, eles não mudam o subdominio.
Não importa o idioma que o usuário escolha, acho que não deve ser passado como parâmetro na URL. Ao meu ver, o idioma é uma opção assim como outra qualquer, onde o usuário escolhe o idioma que será exibido... (`PT`, `EN`, `ES`...).

Alguns sites de noticia usam o idioma na URL, mas não como referência para tradução da linguagem, mas sim como conteúdo regional para exibir o conteúdo de acordo com a região.

A menos que seu site tenha o conteúdo diferenciado como no exemplo acima, eu não recomendo o idioma na URL.

> Imagine que você tenha o idioma na URL:
>   <sub>**pt.example.com | en.example.com**</sub>

Posteriormente, por algum motivo, você decide remover o idioma da URL... Terá que mudar os links, a chance de links quebrados são maiores, tanto externos, quanto internos... Além de correr o risco de considerar duplicidade de link, e isso sim pode e vai diminuir seu PAGERANK.

Os *crawlers* não identificam o idioma na URL.
Seu site pode ter a URL `pt.example.com` ou `portugues.example.com`, o que identifica o idioma é a lingua em que está escrito, e a `TAG-LANG`.

---

Quando um usuário acessa seu site, você identifica a região pelo IP e/ou combinando a opção do idioma do navegador e o sistema vai carregar o pacote de tradução automaticamente.

A definição monetária segue outra regra, se o usuário esta acessando em `PT-BR`, você mostra o valor em real, ou na moeda que ele escolher caso você permita a conversão... Mas essa explicação vai além da URL com parâmetro.

Eu recomendo uma URL limpa, sem parâmetros, pois é de fácil manutenção, com regras simples e sem risco de duplicidade de URLs pelos *crawlers*.

Comment: Até agora não entendi sua resposta, você quis dizer que nenhuma das soluções que mencionei prestam?

Comment: Não disse que não prestam, apenas mostrei casos distintos em que o uso de idioma se faz necessário apenas para diferenciar o conteúdo exibido e não o pacote de tradução

Comment: Mas é porque em alguns casos precisa-se diferenciar o conteúdo. Imagine que no site BR você compra um produto em Reais, já no US você compra em dólares, etc... E que você tenha um Host e venda no BR domínios nacionais, e no MX domínios nacionais também.

Comment: Agora eu entendi o que você que dizer, você me entendeu errado! Eu não me referi o SEO ao nome `pt.meudominio.com` ou `meudominio.com/pt`. Me referi somente pelo fato do PageRank e pelo fato de ser considerado um site sem ligação ao principal `meudominio.com`

Comment: Afinal, você recomenda que eu use subdomínio ou diretório? Sua resposta tá meio confusa.

Comment: Eu não disse que os `crawlers` identificam o idioma pela `URL` isso é lógico. Do mesmo jeito que eu citei `pt.meusite.com` e `meusite.com/pt`, eu poderia ter citado `blog.meusite.com` e `meusite.com/blog`

Comment: Minha resposta foi clara - recomendo uma URL sem parâmetros... Você disse "site multi-línguas" e foi com essa informação que respondi. Os exemplos que você citou(carro, economia) são **palavras** e são MUITO diferentes da abreviação de idioma(PT, EN...), palavras tem peso, por isso disse que crawler não se importa com o idioma na URL - isso não interfere em nada...

Comment: Então não tem problema usar a abreviação do idioma na URL?

Comment: Nem problema nem benefícios... Até onde sei, PAGERANK é individual, o dominio principal não alavanca o subdominio nem vice-versa. O problema maior do que um PAGEHANK baixo, é ser excluído por links duplicados.

Comment: Mas que tipo de links duplicados? Não entendi. Meu site vai ser totalmente traduzido, até mesmo as URLs.

Comment: Se vai traduzir URL então tudo bem. `pt.example.com/pagina-a | en.example.com/page-a` essas duas NÃO são consideradas iguais desde que traduzidas. Se os dois exemplos citados fossem escritos em um só idioma, seria link duplicado.

Comment: Muito bom Papa! Você é o cara! Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28602/dúvidas-sobre-seo

Comment: @Alexandre Lopes, é um assunto bem amplo e interessante que rende muitas linhas, o problema é que estão considerando fora de contexto... vou tentar responder alguma coisa la

Answer (score 0):

Se usar com subdomínio sabe que será tratado pelo google como um outro site que terá sua relevância destacada do domínio principal e terá que trabalhar cada idioma em termos de SEO como se fosse outro site.

Já se utilizar o idioma em diretórios estará garantido o page rank e relevância do domínio para todos os idiomas.