# Dúvidas sobre SEO

Tags: seo

Ultimamente venho me deparado com bastantes dúvidas, e fiquei na vontade de vir aqui publicar algumas delas...

#### Estrutura de URLs

> Qual o maneira correta das URLs?

Vamos supor que eu registre domínios.

`meusite.com.br/produtos/registro-de-dominios`

OU

`meusite.com.br/registro-de-dominios`

Vi no Google que [é bom organizar as páginas por diretórios](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6001176?hl=pt-BR&ref_topic=6001171). Só que vejo nos resultados de pesquisa que isso não tem muita influencia.

---

#### Links Internos

> Como devo linkar as páginas dentro do meu site?

*Parcial:*

```
<a href="pagina"></a>
```

*Completa:*

```
<a href="http://meusite.com/pagina"></a>
```

---

#### A TLD do domínio influencia?

> Se eu usar o domínio com extensão `.com.br` eu terei melhores resultados no Brasil?
>
> Do mesmo modo que eu utilizar `.com.mx` eu terei melhores resultados no México?

O Google intende que o site é de determinado País e direciona mais tráfego para as pessoas que também são do mesmo país?

---

#### Plugin WPMU - WordPress Multilingual

Estava pensando em fazer um Blog e utilizar o WPMU para criar novas línguas.

> Se eu utilizar esse plugin, o Google pode pensar que estou criando conteúdo duplicado e me punir por isso?

Comment: Essa pergunta é sobre SEO, um tema que foi considerado como [fora de contexto pela comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1460/8917)

Comment: Ontem mesmo fiz uma pergunta sobre `SEO` e muitos gostaram. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28425/tenho-um-site-multi-l%c3%adnguas-em-quest%c3%a3o-de-seo-qual-o-melhor-usar-subdom%c3%adnios-o

Comment: O fato da comunidade ter aceito a sua pergunta não condiz com o que está no post do meta. Se realmente quer incentivar posts sobre `SEO` aqui, sugiro que convença as pessoas a votarem a favor no link postado. E sim, agradecimentos não são bem vindos, assim como o seu [comentário acima](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28602/d%c3%bavidas-sobre-seo?noredirect=1#comment53369_28602) o qual acho ofensivo.

Comment: Uma dica a todos: o fato do item sobre SEO estar atualmente com -3 (+1/-4) não significa que ele esteja **definitivamente** fora do foco do site. A comunidade tem voz para decidir essas coisas! Se acham que esse assunto deva ser on-topic, [votem no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1460/8917)! P.S. Não votei pra fechar, e dei um +1 pra anular o -1 - pois achei a pergunta boa; mas no final, é a comunidade que decide se a pergunta permanece ou é fechada

Comment: Eu votei no `META` agora estar `-2`.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun porque está se doendo tanto pela minha pergunta? Qual o mal em criar uma pergunta sobre `SEO`? Assim como eu e outras dezenas, centenas ou até mesmo milhares de usuários do StackOverFlow querem criar perguntas sobre SEO e também querem ser respondidos, pois as respostas não são diretamente por mim, mas pela comunidade. Que eu saiba você não é moderador.

Comment: Eu não tenho nada contra a pergunta, só estou fazendo o que acho correto em relação ao que me parece ser o desejo da comunidade (da forma como definida no meta). Supere os votos negativos lá e poderá postar quantas perguntas de SEO quiser.

Comment: Também gostaria de relembrar que perguntas fechadas podem ser eventualmente reabertas (e vice-versa) se a posição da comunidade mudar em relação ao tópico. Pessoalmente, sigo a diretriz de, na dúvida, deixar aberta, mas o @Kyllopardiun está no direito dele ao votar pra fechar. Por favor, não leve isso pro lado pessoal. E não, nós não somos moderadores, mas em geral é a própria comunidade que se auto-gerencia (ações "de cima" só são empregadas em casos mais graves).

Comment: Pessoalmente interesso-me por `SEO` mas vou seguir e respeitar o que a comunidade votar no meta, sem dúvida. Em relação a esta pergunta específica parece-me serem varias perguntas numa só e dificil de dar resposta de forma razoável.

Comment: Ebâaaaa, obrigado gente! o `SEO` por enquanto tá liberado! Vlw galera! Em especial ao @mgibsonbr e ao @sergio

Comment: Para além de isso ser sobre SEO ou não, será que não deveriam ser 4 perguntas separadas?

Comment: É que eu acho que como se trata de `SEO`, se eu separasse em perguntas individuais, as perguntas se tornariam bobas, perguntas simples. Acredito que juntá-las foi melhor.

Comment: @bfavaretto Quem se interessar em responder, pode responde-las individualmente?

Comment: Quem for responder individualmente teria que empilhar as respostas como você fez, ou vai ficar mais confuso ainda. Eu realmente acho que são perguntas separadas. Se acha que isolada uma pergunta é "boba", pode ser sinal de que precisa dar uma melhorada nela. Por exemplo, as duas primeiras estão formuladas como pedidos de opiniões, não sei se têm resposta correta.

Comment: Obrigado pela compreensão @bfavaretto você pode remover a pergunta, aos poucos vou publicando-as separadamente. Meu medo e de acharem "boba" e quererem votar par fechar. Vejo perguntas de outros usuários que me interessam, que eu acho legais, só que tem gente que vota `-1` ou pede pra `fechar` só com maldade mesmo. Tem gente que entra em pergunta em pergunta só votando contra, só por malvadeza mesmo.

Comment: Pensando bem, vou esperar mais um pouco. Neste momento o @PapaCharlie deve estar criando uma resposta. :D

Comment: Legal, já estão começando a votar a favor! :D

Comment: Acho que essa publicação já deveria ter sido encerrada, concordo com @bfavaretto que são várias questões em uma, até o título está no plural deixando claro que se trata de mais de uma questão. O certo é o autor isolar as questões, não acho elas bobas, acho úteis para quem trabalha com desenvolvimento web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### URLs

> www.dominio.com/noticia1234.htm
>   www.dominio.com/noticia/politica-no-brasil.htm

Aproveitando o exemplo da DOC... é obvio, mas a separação deve ser relevante e coerente relacionando o link com o tipo. O segundo link é o mais intuitivo, relaciona o termo específico( politica no brasil ) a um genero relacionado( noticia ).

Assim como sites de notícia tem suas categorias `noticias | artigos | tempo...` e suas subcategorias. O ideal é sempre agrupar tudo o que for relacionado.

Veja que a navegação se torna intuitiva e similar à navegação em pastas, tornando a organização mais eficiente tanto para os mecanismos de busca quanto para o usuário:

> www.dominio.com/produtos.htm
>   www.dominio.com/produto/hospedagem-de-sites.htm

---

### Link, relativo ou absoluto

O certo é relativo ou absoluto:

> link relativo - /noticia/politica-no-brasil.htm
>   link absoluto - http://www.dominio.com/noticia/politica-no-brasil.htm

Bom, isso vai da preferência do desenvolvedor, eu uso link absoluto por achar mais conveniente e meu sistema produz os links automaticamente.

---

### .COM vs .COM.BR

Existe muita lógica nos motores de busca, eles vão identificar o alvo com base em varios critérios, como o dominio, extensão, idioma... Não posso afirmar categoricamente, pois não encontrei um consenso sobre isso, nem nada muito relevante, a não ser uma certa facilidade em indexar as extensões tradicionais.

---

> Pode ser um debate eterno sem uma certeza concreta... SEO é uma
>   combinação de técnicas sem uma regra exata e simples, mas espero ter
>   ajudado em alguns pontos.

Comment: Isso aí garoto! Você manja em SEO. Rsrs

Comment: Editei o link absoluto. Usando um Framework é mais fácil gerenciar os links com protocolo HTTPS|HTTP.